# Apple Push Notification Not Working in Production xcode8 ios10

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, xcode8, ios10, apns-php

My app getting notification in production yesterday.
Today everything is stop working. I am not able to receive push notification in production system but I can receive push notification in development system.

I have done massive research, however I haven't still fixed the push notification issue. I revoked all the certificate for production and build them from scratch again and again, but still nothing is working.

- who know some good tutorials teach how to setup apple push notification from scratch in production?

After upgraded to xcode 8, I find Automatically manage signing is not working properly. I tried check off Automatically manage signing, I am so confuse about all the Signing things under Build Settings section.
* How Can I Correctly Set Those Signing things in xcode8 ?

I also see some people say 'Device Token is not same in Development and Production System'. Is that true? I keep getting same Device Token in both system. If that is true,
* who could help me guess where are the problems?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your bundle identifier is same with the 'app id' in apple's developer portal. and the push notifications for production is enabled.

[image]

2. Turn on the switch in project settings -> targets -> capabilities.
   If there's any error, revoke certification and try it again.

[image: first]

3. This is my settings when I use 'Automatically manage signing' option.

[image]